# get custom post types using wp rest api v2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to get custom post types, but I can not seem to find any solution. The [WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) documentation only returns blog posts.

**[Tipo.php](https://emailproject.000webhostapp.com/tipo.txt)**
**[Functions.php](https://emailproject.000webhostapp.com/functions.txt)**

Comment: If the custom post type has been registered for REST then just use - /wp-json/wp/v2/xxxxx - where xxxxx is the registered REST post type.

Comment: @magenta How do I check / register?

Comment: check that the call to function register_post_type() has set the REST fields

Comment: @magenta Sorry to be bothering you, but I do not find the function

Below is a copy:
https://emailproject.000webhostapp.com/functions.txt

Comment: Please look again register_post_type must be called to register a post type.

Comment: @magenta Hello again, I found the function in another theme file.

https://emailproject.000webhostapp.com/tipo.txt